# Setting a variable with multiple requirements

Tags: python, numpy

-Disclaimer, I'm new to Python

I'm trying to set a variable to have multiple requirements and I want the outcome to be a boolean value True only when every variable meets the requirements. Sorry if this doesn't make sense, I'm new to these terms. Here's my code:

```
group2 = (color > 1.9 and color < 5) & (mag2 > 23.2 and mag2 < 21.5)
```

and I'm getting this error:

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I'm not sure where to put the a.all().
Edit: color and mag2 are floats in numpy arrays.

Comment: There are hundreds of questions about that error message. Did you try searching for others?

Comment: A little, yes. But I should probably do some more digging.

Comment: what's the data type of color and mag2 variables ?

Comment: @PavanKumarPolavarapu From the error, it appears that these are numpy arrays.

Comment: Replace `and` with `&`